# How to define the rated efficiency of an induction motor

Tags: voltage, power, current, induction-motor, efficiency

I have a bunch of pictures of motor nameplates (all 3 phase induction motors) and I've been asked to report the rated efficiency of each motor.

At the beginning I was doing:

$$\eta_\text{rated} = \frac{\text{Rated Power}}{\sqrt{3} \times V_\text{rated} \times I_\text{rated} \times \text{pf}_\text{rated}}$$

But then I noted that some motors (not all) also have a "Rated Efficiency" on the nameplate, for example (taken from https://www.electricportal.info/2019/11/how-to-read-motors-nameplate-data.html?utm_content=cmp-true):

[image]

Most of the time, the values are (more or less) the same. For the example above, using the formula gives me (using a power factor of 0.82):

$$\eta_\text{rated} = \frac{1500\text{W}}{\sqrt{3} \times 220\text{V} \times 5.9\text{A} \times 0.82} = 81.4\%$$

The question is, what is the correct way to define the rated efficiency? Is the formula I used always correct? Or should I rather use the efficiency as given in the nameplate (when available)?

Also, if the formula is right, why is the efficiency also included in the nameplate, if it can be deduced from the rated power?

Comment: A well labelled motor allows you to crosscheck - exactly as you did - and increase your confidence that the motor will work as stated. Too often you find missing or even contradictory information - then, buyer beware!